# Index of item in ArrayList w/o using IndexOf but Using an Additional Data Structure Instead - Java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, indexof

I simulate a cache replacement algorithm. I have a cache implemented as an arraylist that fills in with the requested items (objects of custom-type Request). These objects are identified by their unique numeric ID (reqID) - for N items, an integer between 1 and N. I insert items in the cache from the start of the cache arraylist and evict them from the end. That is,

```
// insertion
this.cache.add(0, item);

// eviction
this.cache.remove(this.cache.size()-1);
```

I maintain the cache arraylist sorted according to the score of the items which I keep in a HashMap reqID (K) - score (V).

At some point in my code I have to check for cache reordering due to a cache hit (since the score of that cached item is increased by 1). If required, in order to keep the cache ordered, the requested item and the item at its left in the cache arraylist will exchange position in the cache.

Therefore, I have to know the index of the requested item in the cache. I can use the following:

```
int ind = this.cache.indexOf(request);
```

and therefore the index of the next item at its left will be:

```
int indLeft = ind - 1;
```

and thus I will be able easilly to exchange their position in the cache arraylist.

However, I would really like to avoid using indexOf since it makes use internally of a for loop. Hence, I will have to store the positions of the items in some data structure. What kind of data structure would you suggest? My first thought was a HashMap positions (reqID - index) due to constant complexity of the operations that I care about, but then I noticed that each time I insert an item in the cache, the index of the other items is increased by 1. How could I possibly increase by 1 the value of all the previous keys (reqIDs) in that positions map each time I put a new key-value pair without using a for loop? Thus, probably some other data structure is required. Or some other idea...

Comment: So you're implementing a LRU cache, right?

Comment: Why don't you use a linked list in pair with a map?

Comment: @WeiboLi       Actually, no! :) I simulate an LFU-like replacement algorithm for web caching. I have a sliding window of the last K requests and I restrict the LFU principle in this sliding "time-frame". In other words, any time a request is inserted into the window (pushing one index right the previous requests), the score of that item increases by 1, and each time a request is evicted from the window, the score of that item is decreased by 1. According to the score of the items in the cache, I maintain the cache ordered using e.g. a reordering method when there is a cache hit (+1 for an

Comment: @WeiboLi       item) or eviction of request from the window (-1 for an item) - if that item is in the cache. The window could be an arraylist or linkedlist, no real difference there I guess.

Comment: @svz           Could you explain your idea in a little more detail please?

Comment: @Kotsos if you're using one-dimensional array and you would like to find element index based on its reqID in constant time, you have no other option but to keep hashmap reqID-index and update indexes whenever the objects move around. however, these updates are not going to occur on every single hit, whereas `indexOf` will occur on every hit

Comment: @Kotsos by the way, your dealing with this expression `the requested item and the item at its left` is a bit confusing. probably you meant `the itemS at its left` ? because if the updated item score is larger than the item on its left (LFU), it should be repeatedly swapped with elements on its left, until the left item score is eventually larger, just like in insertion sort

Comment: @mangusta      You are right about the continuing swapping, but my goal is to have a replacement algorithm that is more efficient than LRU (since it takes into account request count, i.e. frequency information, which is more important than time-of-access, i.e. recency information in web caching), able to react to popularity dynamics (that's why I use a limited backlog memory - the sliding window - which acts as an aging mechanism to avoid cache pollution with outdated formerly popular items) and still fast as LRU (which is suboptimal in terms of the hit rate but simple and fast and thus the...

Comment: @mangusta      ... the "standard" choise of replacement algorithm in web caching solutions). For the third point, I thought that keeping the cache ordered in terms of the score of the items gives me an advantage - and indeed that's the case, since for example in replacement I don't have to scan the cache to find the "least-valuable" item which is the item to be evicted from the cache: it will always be the right-most item in the cache arraylist. In order to keep processing time low, I compare in case of a cache hit the relevant cached item only with its item at its left. This results in a ...

Comment: @mangusta      ... partially sorted cache in a few cases, but most of the time is ok, while at the same time I achieve two of the previously mentioned goals (with the hit rate being much better than LRU, close to the optimum one). Only the run time is still much higher than LRU, and this is due to the indexOf operation which I need to reorder the cache in case of a cache hit or eviction of a request from the window (when I compare the score of the relevant item with the item at its left or right, respectively, in the cache). Thus, if I have somehow index information for the items in cache ...

Comment: @mangusta      ... I will avoid the indexOf method and I will achieve good run time (hopefully, close to the one of LRU).

Comment: @mangusta      Regarding your other comment, since in any insertion of an item in the cache (at the start of the cache arraylist), the others are right-shifted by one index, then if I use a HashMap with K-V pair reqID - indexInCache, how will I update the indexes of the previous keys (reqIDs) in that HashMap (i.e. increase them by 1) in each cache insertion without using a for loop for the HashMap (which again means performance drop, i.e. I will not avoid the problem that I am trying to avoid at first place).

Comment: @Kotsos well, yeah, in case if the number of insertions is supposed to be larger than the hits, then reqID-index hashing gives no advantage over using `indexOf` :) otherwise you're better off using hashing

Comment: When you have to say **SO** much in the comments, you should consider editing the question instead, and include the relevant information (in a concise and readable form!) there. Just an aside: `cache.add(0, item)` will also have O(n) on an `ArrayList` (similar to `indexOf`)

Comment: @Marco13       You are right. Actually, I was not going to give so much details because I thought they were irrelevant. It just came up with the discussion. Regarding cache.add(0, item), you are right again, but I didn't think of a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your arraylist, but to more efficiently find, replace, and remove, you can use 2 dimensional arraylist if you are incorporating blocks and then a hashtable to index the elements.

So anytime you get a "hit", you can grab the key and replace it from your arraylist. This method requires no loops.

Answer (score 0):

Create a CacheItem class to wrap your key, value and score.

```
public class CacheItem {

        private String key;

        private Object value;

        private int score;

//getters and setters
}
```

Then implement the cache pool with `HashMap`:

```
//cache pool structure
Map<String, CacheItem> cache = new HashMap<String, CacheItem>();

CacheItem item = cache.get("somekey");
if(item != null) {      //hit
    item.setScore(item.getScore() + 1); //incr score
}
```

But when you want to check the score of each cache item, you must use a loop.